# Append Date Timestamp as a column to existing DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, append

In power bi

1. Combining two power bi queries - one with data & one with DateTime stamp text string
2. fill down DateTime field - adding a custom column,

I am trying to achieve the same in python's data frame with no luck!

any help is greatly appreciated.

The Error that I am getting is as shown in the image.
[datetime stamp as appended column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lGDp.png)

My code :

```
import requests
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    from time import gmtime, strftime
    import datetime
    from datetime import datetime

class NseIndia2:

    def __init__(self):
        self.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'}
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.session.get("http://nseindia.com", headers=self.headers)


    def get_option_chain(self, symbol, indices=False):
        if not indices:
            url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=' + symbol
        else:
            url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=' + symbol
           
        time = self.session.get(url,headers=self.headers).json()["records"]['timestamp']       
#         output 28-Oct-2021 13:16:44
#         print(time)
#         web_datetime = datetime.strptime(time,'%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
#         print(dtm)
#         output 2021-10-28 13:58:45
        
        data = self.session.get(url,headers=self.headers).json()["records"]["data"]
        
        
        my_df = []
        for i in data:
            for k, v in i.items():
                if k == "CE" or k == "PE":
                    info = v
                    info["instrumentType"] = k
                    my_df.append(info)
        return pd.DataFrame(my_df)


nse = NseIndia2()

##print(nse.get_stock_info("RELIANCE"))
df= (nse.get_option_chain("NIFTY",indices=True))

df.loc[:,"recordedat"] = time.time() ##?This is where i need web's date-time details instead of sciencitfic number

##print(df)
print(df["recordedat"])
Print(df)
```

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Comment: it seems you forgot `()` to execute function - like `time()`. Or maybe rather `time.time()`

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot `()` to execute function `time()` - or rather `time.time()`

```
df.loc[:, "Timestamp"] = time.time()
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want normal time and date then simply use `datetime

```
df.loc[:, "Timestamp"] = datetime.datetime.now()
```

**BTW:**

You can write it shorter

```
df["Timestamp"] = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: you ask for timestamp and `1.635410e+09` is timestamp but it may display it in science notation. If you use `print(1.635410e+09)` then you can see `1635410000.0` . But if you want current time and date then simply use `datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: Thanks heaps.There is a  small problem with `time. time()` it returns the number as `1.635410e+09` instead of `28-Oct-2021 13:58:45` or `2021-10-28 13:58:45`

Originally website with DateTime stamp as
`
#28-Oct-2021 13:16:44


`time = self.session.get(url,headers=self.headers).json()["records"]['timestamp']       
        # output 28-Oct-2021 13:16:44
        print(time)
        date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(time,'%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
        print(date_time_obj)
        # output 2021-10-28 13:58:45`

 `df.loc[:,"recordedat"] = time.time() ` how to reflect date timestamp ?

Comment: I want timestamp from website only as there may be a delay & would like to record the delay (if any).Inshort it is crucial to use datetime stamp mentioned in website instead of `datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: if you need value `time` and `date` then  DON'T use `time.time()` but simply `datetime.datetime.now()` . And if you want value from `JSON` then assing this value `date_time_obj` to `dataframe`. And if you want delay then substract both values `datetime.datetime.now() - date_time_obj` - but this gives `timedelta`, not `datettime` and it will display it in different way.

Comment: Sorry for the bad code reply.I need JSON date & timestamp from website only & in Date time format .please ignore my explanation about time delay or time delta. Thanks for all your help btw.

Comment: datetime keeps current date `day-month-year` but delay is only number of seconds between two dates - and it doesn't have somethink like `day-month-year`. Eventually It may have only number of days between dates. You can't display delay `2 days` as `02-january-2021`

Comment: @Furas.let me explain it a bit better. Apologies for my confusion. Date & time stamp on the website is the time which I can use to append with data frame as i am using this code in a while loop with 5 minutes intervals to gather data for every 5 minutes. data on the website is always 'late' around 5 to 10 minutes & hence date timestamp of the website is very important to distinguish between two downloads at a diff time interval. This is the reason why i don't want to use `datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: I don't don't understanda what you want to do. If you need current `date time` then `datetime.datetime.now()` is more usefull then `time.time()` because you can directly substract two `datetime` objects to get delay - `date_time_obj1 - date_time_obj2`. And if you need to move value in `datetime` - ie. add 5 minutes - then you can add `datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)` to objects `datetime` like `date_time_obj + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)`

Comment: BTW: maybe better show in question example dataframe - as text so we could simply copy and run it - and what result you want to get.

Comment: I read more about time.time( ) - it is actually related to current date & time same as DateTime now(). Actually, I have a variable called "time" which was actually web_refresh_time. That's what I tried to append to data frame an extra column. hope this clarifies

Comment: I see you have variable `time` - but it is local variable which exists only inside `get_option_chain` and you would have to use `return time, pd.DataFrame()` and later `time, df = nse.get_option_chain(...)` to have this value outside function. OR maybe you should use it directly inside `get_option_chain` and first create `df = pd.DataFrame()`, next assign value `df['..'] = time` and finally use `return df`